# Select Menu via JavaScript: not working (`undefined`) in Mozilla, but working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, mozilla

I put `<li>` data in drop down box. "Inspect element" option shows the text is there but is does not show up in the drop down.

Here is my html and js code.

**HTML**

```
<h1>
                <ul class="lev1">
                    <li>
                        menu-1
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        menu-2
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        menu-3
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        menu-4
                    </li>
                </ul>
  </h1>

        <select id="select2-menu" name="term" class="search_product">
            <option>
                All
            </option>
        </select>
```

**JavaScript**

```
    <script>
    var ul=document.getElementsByClassName('lev1');
        var li = ul[0].getElementsByTagName('li');
        var select = document.getElementById('select2-menu');

        for (var i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
            var option = document.createElement("option");
            option.value = li[i].innerText;
            option.text = li[i].innerText;
            select.add(option, null);
            try {
                select.add(option, null); //Standard
            } catch (error) {
                select.add(option); // IE only
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: where is lev1 class, i didn't see in your code

Comment: Where is the list with class "lev1" ? Could you provide a JSFiddle? The question is very hard to understand.

Comment: <h1>
        <ul class="lev1">
            <li>
                menu-1
            </li>
            <li>
                menu-2
            </li>
            <li>
                menu-3
            </li>
            <li>
                menu-4
            </li>
        </ul>
    </h1>

    <select id="select2-menu" name="term" class="wd_search_product">
        <option>
            All
        </option>
    </select>

Comment: `innerText` is not supported in FF, use `textContent` instead.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/a6wa9z1y/

Comment: textContent not workin in FF

Comment: @AnkitVirani No? [Did you even try](http://jsfiddle.net/wzuartLp/) ... And [a good reason](http://jsfiddle.net/wzuartLp/1/) why `innerHTML` would be a bad idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<script>
     var ul=document.getElementsByClassName('lev1');
            var li = ul[0].getElementsByTagName('li');
            var obj = document.getElementById('select2-menu');

            for (var i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
                var opt = document.createElement("option");
                opt.value = li[i].innerHTML;
                opt.text = li[i].innerHTML;
                //select.add(option, null);
                obj.appendChild(opt);
            }
</script>
```

Comment: But one problem white space take in value.  <select id="select2-menu" name="term" class="wd_search_product">
        <option>
            All
        </option>
    <option value="
                menu-1
            ">
                menu-1
            </option><option value="
                menu-2
            ">
                menu-2
            </option><option value="
                menu-3
            ">
                menu-3
            </option><option value="
                menu-4
            ">
                menu-4
            </option></select>

Comment: If its solved your problem accept this as your answer

Comment: You have white space in your ul li. remove it